# Question about conjugate of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I was reading legendre transform and this is what I got Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function then there associates another convex function $f^*$ define by $f^*=sup\{xy-f(x),x\geq 0\}$,
My question is if $f$ is differentiable then we can find $f^*$ but what will happen when $f$ is not differentiable, can someone give an example? Also if someone explains the geometrical interpretation of this or provides some books where I can read about it in more detail then that will be a great help.

Comment: There is no $x \ge 0$ constraint in general.

Comment: so you mean $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In general, yes.

Comment: There are many examples, look for convex conjugate or Fenchel conjugate, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101023/27978. Convex Analysis by Rockafellar and Boyd and Vandenberghe's book.

Comment: For example, $|\cdot|^*(y)$ is given by $0$ for $|y| \le 1$ and $+\infty$ otherwise.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, one more thing can you please explain why we need conjugate a convex function?

Comment: Make this into a separate question.